# Cardinality of $E=\left\{\left(x,y\right):x,y>0\text{ and }x+y,xy\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I want to find the cardinality of $$E=\left\{\left(x,y\right):x,y>0\text{ and }x+y,xy\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2.$$

This problem came from a recent real analysis comprehensive exam that I took, and I was not able (in my mind) to adequately answer the question. My intuition tells me that there are no two transcendental numbers whose sum and product are both rational, and since $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}^2\subseteq E$ trivially, I thought me that maybe $E\subset A\times A$ (not equal, as pointed out by Crostul) where $A$ is the set of all positive real numbers which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $A$ is countable, this would make $E$ countable. That is essentially all that I could put for my solution. Thankfully, I did well enough on the rest of the exam that I passed, and I will be graduating with a Master's degree in Mathematics.

I do not know where to go from my intuition, and I do not even know that it is correct. Any push in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Obviously $E \subset A \times A$ is a strict inequality (for example $(\sqrt{2}, 1) \notin E$).

Comment: @Crostul Oh, yes, of course. Thank you, I'm not sure why I didn't think about that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $(x, y) \in E$, and call $a=x+y, b=xy \in \Bbb{Q}$. Then $x,y$ are exactly the two roots of the polynomial $T^2-aT+b \in \Bbb{Q}[T]$, so they are algebraic numbers of degree at most 2.

Comment: Thank you! I see it, now! Is it possible that $E=\mathbb{Q}^2$, or could there be an example of a pair of strictly algebraic real numbers which satisfy this, as well?

Comment: @BrianScholl In my answer take $b$ a prime integer, for example.

Comment: @ajotatxe Thank you, this is very helpful. I see now that, for example, $\left(2+\sqrt{2},2-\sqrt{2}\right)\in E$.

Answer (score 2):

These are the pairs of roots of equations like
$$(X-a)^2=b$$

where $a\in \Bbb Q$ and $b\in\Bbb Q_{>0}$.

(Namely, $x+y=2a$, $xy=a^2-b$).

Hence, countable.